# Using skip and take for data in angular 2 and showing data as it comes

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, ng2-smart-table

I am trying to show data as it comes in from the API.

What I am doing is:

```
var qstring = ['http://localhost:57398/api/values/passdata?query=select * from t1 order by id offset 0 rows fetch next 1000 rows only', 'http://localhost:57398/api/values/passdata?query=select * from t1 order by id offset 1000 rows fetch next 1000 rows only', 'http://localhost:57398/api/values/passdata?query=select * from t1 order by id offset 2000 rows fetch next 1000 rows only', 'http://localhost:57398/api/values/passdata?query=select * from t1 order by id offset 3000 rows fetch next 1000 rows only'];

return Observable.from(qstring).mergeMap(d => this.http.get(d).map(res => res.json() as any));
```

to Bind

```
source: any;

 this.service.getDataFromServer().subscribe(data => {
            this.source = this.sdata;
        }, Error => {
            console.log(Error);
        });
```

Template

```
 <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" ></ng2-smart-table>
```

But it only shows the last one. How can I make sure that data is appended and not overriden?

Comment: Updated bindings

Comment: What console.log(qstring) does give you. I think your problem resides there.

Comment: There's no error as it overrides, so i used an array to bind it to grid which seems like a hack

newItems: any[] = [];

for (var element in data) {  
                let marker = data[element];
                this.newItems.push(
                    {
                        id: marker.id
                    })
            }

            this.source = this.newItems;

Comment: So source data didn't have the correct format, i.e didn't have {id:...} but it had the whole query result  without id key? It's not a hack :)